# Escalar un ajuste lognormal simple a una suma lognormal en python

Tags: python, numpy, function

estoy tratando de ajustar unos datos que presentan una distribución lognormal. Puedo ajustar los datos para una sola población pero me pregunto cual es la manera correcta de ajustar multiples distribuciones lognormales. Por ejemplo, para 2 poblaciones con distribución normal la función que describe los datos es una suma de funciones gaussianas. Pero para una para mas de una distribución lognormal no entiendo cual es la manera de representar esta distribución. My codigo es el siguiente:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Primero genero 3 poblaciones con distribución lognormal:
import numpy as np

s1 = np.random.lognormal(2, 0.6, 1000)  #mu and sigma
s2 = np.random.lognormal(1.6, 0.3, 1000) #mu and sigma
s3 = np.random.lognormal(1.8, 0.5, 1000) #mu and sigma

mb = np.max([s1,s2,s3])
X = np.arange(1,mb,1)
 #histogram population 1
Y11, bins1 = np.histogram(s1, X)
Y1 = Y11/Y11.sum()
X1 = bins1[:-1]

 #histogram population 2
Y22, bins2 = np.histogram(s2, X)
Y2 = Y22/Y22.sum()
X2 = bins2[:-1]

 #histogram population 3
Y33, bins3 = np.histogram(s3, X)
Y3 = Y33/Y33.sum()
X3 = bins3[:-1]

 #Aqui presento la suma de las 3 distribuciones con distintos parámetros 
S =  np.concatenate((s1, s2, s3), axis=None)


Yi, bins = np.histogram(S, X)
Y = Yi/Yi.sum()
X = bins[:-1]

def logN(x, mu, sigma):
      
    return  (np.exp(-(np.log(x) - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma **2)) / (x * sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)))  #lognormal function

params, pcov = curve_fit(logN, X,Y, method="lm")
print(params)
plt.plot(X1, Y1, 'o')
plt.plot(X2, Y2, 'o')
plt.plot(X3, Y3, 'o')
plt.plot(X, Y, 'r-o')
plt.plot(X, logN(X ,params[0], params[1])) 

plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi objetivo es llegar a los parámetros 'mu' de las 3 poblaciones por separado. Los datos reales comienzan con datos como 'S'y mi función describe una distribución lognormal simple, pero no entiendo como poder llegar a los parámetros que componen esta distribución. Cualquier idea es bien recibida

Comment: Parece más un problema de estadística que de programación.

Comment: Tiene sentido, gracias por el aporte